# C++ ShellExecute a URL

Tags: c++, url, shellexecute

Tried googling for a few hours, testing different solutions for hours but still just cannot get this to work.

I need a const url base (Ex. http://www.google.com)
Then I need a string input from the user (ex. Mountain Dew) and then combine them.
I've tried making the URL a LPCWSTR, wstring, wchar_t, doing a function to convert them and combine  them but I cannot get it to work at all.

```
std::string baseUrl = "http://www.google.com/";
std::string userAdd;
getline(std::cin, userAdd)
ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), baseUrl + userAdd, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'combining' them ? The output should be "http://www.google.comMountain Dew" ?

Comment: Can you put on what code you have for us first?

Comment: So, basically, you want to open a browser page to google.com, and then fill in "Mountain Dew" into the search field, and display the results? I've not tried, but my understanding both of Windows ShellExecute and generally how web-things work says that this is more complex than just calling `ShellExecute`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it to just be one big url like, google was an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no automatic conversion from std::string to const char*.

Try this:  `(baseUrl + userAdd).c_str()`

and try using ShellExecuteA

Comment: That does it perfectly!
    ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", (baseUrl + userAdd).c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);